# Detecting mouse hover over arc

Tags: javascript

Hi there I'm having trouble detecting my mouse hover over a particular section of my donut chart. Basically when my mouse hovers over a particular section of the donut chart, it would display the percentage of that particular data. Im coding in javascript, would appreciate the help thanks!!

I can only code this through JS so CSS would not be viable for me.

Comment: Can u show your current code of chart?

Comment: Hi there which section?

Comment: You can use the mouseover event: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseover_event

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to perform some action on hover - the easiest way is to use css :hover to change style of child div/span from `display: none` to `display: block`

However the same can be done using JavaScript using as Emil suggested - useMouseOver. So you can have a function that changes the `element.style.display = block` when onmouseover and with onmouseout  - set it back to `none`